# No injecta librerías wiredep con gulp

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

Estoy tratando de configurar `wiredep`en mi proyecto y no lo he logrado. Configuré el `gulp-inject` y está funcionando. ¿En qué estoy fallando?

`html`

```
<!-- bower:css -->
<!-- endbower -->
```

`Gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
  gulp.src('./app/index.html')
          .pipe(wiredep({
                directory: './app/lib'
                }))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
});
gulp.watch(['./bower.json'], ['wiredep']);
```

`.bowerrc`

```
{
 "directory": "app/lib"
}
```

Gracias